# How can I inject code in python programs so that they can print the conditions inside the if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, instrumentation

I am looking for a way to instrument (Inject code inside) python programs. 
For example, if a program hits the `if` condition `x > 2`, I want to automatically add a `print` statement following the `if` condition which prints to the console `x > 2`.

The source code of the program is not available.

Comment: Do you mean *without* explicitly using the `logging` module in your code or using a debugger?

Comment: @chepner yeah without those. I intend to record the **if** statements when they're executed (or **else** when **if** is not executed) and print their conditions out. Not looking for a debugger.

Comment: why not just add a print statement after an if?

Comment: @user1767754 how would I do that? Given a custom python program, I wouldn't know what the if conditions are? I want automation.

Comment: @AliAhsan then maybe you should make it clear in your question that you want this result on a programme for which you don't have access to the source code. Equally, don't say that you want to add a `print` statement as this makes it feel like you just want to write a `print` statement in the code, as opposed to automatically print the value of any conditional test.

Comment: @ArthurSpoon yeah I feel like there is some sort of confusion. I will clear that up in the question. Apologies for the miscommunication?

Comment: well could you then add in the question that you don't have access to the source code? still saying "my python programs". it sounds very much like you are injecting codes into source codes that you don't own. i.e. a bit like reverse engineering.

Comment: If the source is not available can you be more specific about what you do have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ast` module, but you still need the sources. If you have only the bytecode, you must use something like [uncompyle6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6/) in order to get the source back - since you are doing this automatically it doesn't matter if the source is obfuscated.

Suppose you have a module like this:

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 100:
        print('big')
    else:
        print('small')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(5)
    foo(500)
```

If you exec foo, you get:

```
small
big
```

Now you want to print the test clause of every `if` statement if the test is `True`. Lets start by importing foo:

```
>>> import foo
```

Then get the source code:

```
>>> source = inspect.getsource(foo)
```

Lets parse the source in order to get an abstract syntax tree:

```
>>> tree = ast.parse(source)
```

The next step is defining a NodeTransformer that will modify the tree:

```
>>> class IfTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
         def visit_If(self, node):
             new_node = ast.Expr(value=ast.Call(
                  func=ast.Name(id='print', ctx=ast.Load()), 
                  args=[ast.Str(s=astunparse.unparse(node.test))], 
                  keywords=[]
             ))
             node.body.insert(0, new_node)
             return ast.fix_missing_locations(node)
```

In order to modify the tree we make our `IfTransformer` visit all nodes:

```
>>> IfTransformer().visit(tree)
```

Then you can compile and execute your new source:

```
>>> exec(compile(tree, 'foo.py', 'exec'))
(__name__ == '__main__')

small
(x > 100)

big
```

For each `if` clause where the test is True, you got the test printed. A smart guy like you can figure everything out from here.

Check out [this video from Pycon 2011](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2011/pycon-2011--what-would-you-do-with-an-ast.html).

Comment: It is worth pointing that except of `ast` module one needs to import `inspect` and `astunparse` to get this example running :)