# Instrumenting Python Code

Tags: python, instrumentation

I want to instrument every if condition encountered inside a python function automatically. For example if my code hits:

```
if x > 2:
    #do something
```

I want to record/ print "x > 2" to the console.

I found this tool "equip" https://github.com/neuroo/equip/
but it only instuments at function boundaries. I think I need to be able to instrument at the bytecode instruction level to get those conditionals out.

Currently, I have to manually stdout/append after every if condition like

```
if x > 2:    
    list.append("x>2")
```

Comment: I guess your best shot is patching the AST using the inspect and ast modules. Unfortunately a proper answer would require more time than I have right now.

Comment: interestingly just read another pal's question looking almost identical to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380733/how-can-i-inject-code-in-python-programs-so-that-they-can-print-the-conditions-i if you see the tool you posted you will see they only give you details of functions called and their signatures respectively. but they don't to reverse engineering. e.g injection of codes into source codes you don't own in order to replicate/get hold of the source codes. it's fine you are learning, but it may sound suspicious, so please give enough details.

Comment: @stucash rofl I just noticed he is my project partner. And we are both stuck at the same problem :/ Yes, now that I think about it - it is similar to reverse engineering. For now our task is to make an AST of any given python function and pass it to Z3 theorem solver (in python). It works fine if we manually make a tree/list of all the conditionals, but we are required to instrument it automatically.

Comment: @PauloScardine Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Elaborating: start by calling `inspect.getsource` in order to get the source code of the module, compile it to AST using `ast.parse` and inspect/patch the AST looking for instances of `_ast.If` and adding a print call for their `test` clause, then compile and run it. I don't know for you, but this kind of incantation is above my wizardry level - that is why I don't have time for a proper answer - but it is very doable. If this is for debugging, why no just use pdb?

Comment: @PauloScardine If it is very doable and supposedly useful then I'm having a hard time figuring why doesn't such a tool already exist? (or difficult to find) Anyway thanks alot for your help. Guess inspect and ast modules is where I need to dive now. Btw, it is not for debugging.

Answer (score 10):

This is a simple example to get you started. Suppose you have a module like this:

```
def foo(x):
    if x > 100:
        print('big')
    else:
        print('small')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo(5)
    foo(500)
```

If you exec foo, you get:

```
small
big
```

Now you want to print the test clause of every `if` statement if the test is `True`. Lets start by importing foo:

```
>>> import foo
```

Then get the source code:

```
>>> source = inspect.getsource(foo)
```

Lets parse the source in order to get an abstract syntax tree:

```
>>> tree = ast.parse(source)
```

The next step is defining a NodeTransformer that will modify the tree:

```
>>> class IfTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
         def visit_If(self, node):
             new_node = ast.Expr(value=ast.Call(
                  func=ast.Name(id='print', ctx=ast.Load()), 
                  args=[ast.Str(s=astunparse.unparse(node.test))], 
                  keywords=[]
             ))
             node.body.insert(0, new_node)
             return ast.fix_missing_locations(node)
```

In order to modify the tree we make our `IfTransformer` visit all nodes:

```
>>> IfTransformer().visit(tree)
```

Then you can compile and execute your new source:

```
>>> exec(compile(tree, 'foo.py', 'exec'))
(__name__ == '__main__')

small
(x > 100)

big
```

For each `if` clause where the test is True, you got the test printed. A smart guy like you can figure everything out from here.

Check out [this video from Pycon 2011](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2011/pycon-2011--what-would-you-do-with-an-ast.html).